How to change Linux launch configuration?
When I create launch configuration for project, VS Code generates this code:
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "АА.Core",
            "type": "dotnet",
            "request": "launch",
            "projectPath": "${workspaceFolder}/АА/АА.Core/АА.Core.csproj",
            "launchConfigurationId": "TargetFramework=;АА.Core"
        }
    ]
}

But when I was starting debugging, it starting this task (you can see win-x64 folder):
Executing task: dotnet: build /home/u/Projects/AA/AA/AA.Core/AA.Core.csproj 

dotnet build /home/u/Projects/AA/AA/AA.Core/AA.Core.csproj /property:GenerateFullPaths=true /consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary 
MSBuild version 17.3.2+561848881 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  AA.Core -> /home/u/Projects/AA/AA/AA.Core/bin/Debug/net6.0/win-x64/AA.dll
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it

In my .csproj I have this configuration:
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'DebugLinux64' ">
        <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
        <DefineConstants>TRACE;IO_SUPPORTED;DEBUG;OS_LINUX</DefineConstants>
        <RuntimeIdentifier>linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    </PropertyGroup>

How can I set DebugLinux64 configuration when debugging?
